# The last modified time of a file is a 13 digit number. What does it mean?

Tags: java, file, last-modified

```
    long lastmodify   =   f.lastModified();
    System.out.println("File Lost Modify:"+lastmodify);
```

I am running the above code of file("f"), but it displays the last modified time is:1267082998588
I am confusing, is this is time or not.? Actually what it is?

Comment: Venkats, please don't forget to accept the answer that helped you most - and revisit your history of recent question to do it there as well. That's how SO works.

Comment: Venkats, your instinctive response should be to look up the function in the Javadocs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

Try:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat().format(new Date(f.lastModified())));
```

You can do whatever you want with the Date.  See [Date](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), and [GregorianCalendar](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) in particular.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the [File](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#lastModified%28%29) documentation. It returns the miliseconds since 00:00:00 GMT, January 1, 1970.

You can do this instead

```
long lastmodify = f.lastModified();
Date modified = new Date(lastmodify);
System.out.println("File Lost Modify:"+ modified);
```

Answer (score 5):

It *says* it gives the answer in milliseconds, but apparently it does not, it gives the answer in *seconds* multiplied by a thousand:

```
bsh % File x = new File("/vmlinuz");     
bsh % print(x.lastModified());      
1318019877000
```

In Linux, even with ext4 (which has microsecond resolution), all files end in 000! Apparently in Windows you will get noise at the end, but it should not be mistaken for milliseconds, it is, they say, "an approximation"

Comment: I confirm this issue.  I had tests rapidly writing files, then checking last modified timestamp.  Works on Windows, but fails on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Javadoc of the method in the File class (it is clear enough):

**public long lastModified()**

Returns the time that the file denoted by this abstract pathname was last modified.

Returns:
A long value representing the time the file was last modified, **measured in milliseconds since the epoch (00:00:00 GMT, January 1, 1970)**, or 0L if the file does not exist or if an I/O error occurs

Answer (score 1):

```
    long lastmodify   =   f.lastModified();
    Date dt=new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat date   = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String modify=date.format(lastmodify);
```

This is also one of the answer i got..

Answer (score 0):

That is the date [represented in milliseconds] that the file was edited.  It is the amount of milliseconds that have passed since January 1st, 1970 [also known as the Unix Epoch]